# Excel sheet renaming won't work

Tags: c#, excel, renaming

I want to rename the specified worksheet and put some processed data on it, but the following code (which looks almost the same as every example I could find on this and other websites) just won't to what I want:

```
try
{
    xl.Worksheet = (ExcelRefer.Worksheet) xl.Workbook.Worksheets.get_Item("Sheet1");
    xl.Worksheet.Name = "Smoothed result";
    xl.Workbook.Save();
    xl.Range = xl.Worksheet.UsedRange;

    Debug.WriteLine("Saved");
}
catch(Exception exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
}
```

The exception is never thrown, so the code doesn't contain any errors but the worksheet in the document I've opened still has the same name. Also, the

```
Debug.WriteLine(...)
```

method is called and the output is correctly displayed. It does even ask me if I want to overwrite the existing file when I tell the Workbook to save. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:**

`xl` is an object of a class that contains all necessary elements for working with excel.

```
using ExcelRefer = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using ZedGraph;
class XLSXMulti
{
    private static List<int[]> dataPositions = new List<int[]>();
    private static PointPairList measureData = new PointPairList();
    private static PointPairList[] dataComparison = new PointPairList[2];
    private static bool smoothing = false;
    private static bool measureDataFound = false;
    private static bool fileFinished = false;
    private static string[] excelFilePaths;
    private static string[] temp;
    private static int numberOfSamples;
    private static BackgroundWorker[] bwg;
    private static ProgressBar pbExcel;

    public static void Init(string[] filePaths, ProgressBar pb, bool smooth)
    {
        excelFilePaths = filePaths;
        pbExcel = pb;
        smoothing = smooth;
        measureData.Clear();
        dataPositions.Clear();

        temp = Interaction.InputBox("Number of consecutive values to be used " +
                                    "for smoothing and the iteration step. These values" +
                                    " will be used for all selected files.\n" +
                                    "IMPORTANT: The two values have to be separated with a ','!",
                                    "Select grade of smoothing",
                                    "5,1", 500, 480).Split(',');


        bwg = new BackgroundWorker[Environment.ProcessorCount];
        for(int i = 0; i < bwg.Length; i ++)
        {
            bwg[i] = new BackgroundWorker();
        }

        foreach(BackgroundWorker bw in bwg)
        {
            bw.DoWork += bwg_doWork;
            bw.ProgressChanged += bwg_ProgressChanged;
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bwg_RunworkerCompleted;

            bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        }

        List<string>[] filesForWorkers = new List<string>[bwg.Length];
        for(int i = 0; i < filesForWorkers.Length; i ++)
        {
            filesForWorkers[i] = new List<string>();
        }

        int filesPerWorker = filePaths.Length / bwg.Length;
        int workerindex = 0;

        MessageBox.Show("filesPerWorker: " + filesPerWorker + "\n" +
                        "filePaths: " + filePaths.Length + "\n" +
                        "bwg: " + bwg.Length);

        for(int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i ++)
        {
            filesForWorkers[workerindex].Add(filePaths[i]);

            workerindex ++;
            if(workerindex == bwg.Length)
            {
                workerindex = 0;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < bwg.Length; i ++)
        {
            bwg[i].RunWorkerAsync(filesForWorkers[i]);
        }
    }

    private static void bwg_doWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> filelist = e.Argument as List<string>;
        Excelattributes xl = new Excelattributes();

        foreach(string s in filelist)
        {
            try
            {
                xl.App = new ExcelRefer.Application();
                xl.Workbook = xl.App.Workbooks.Open(s, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, 
                                                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
                xl.Worksheet = (ExcelRefer.Worksheet)xl.Workbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1); // Zugriff auf eingegebenes Tabellenblatt
                xl.Range = xl.Worksheet.UsedRange;

                findMeasureData(xl);

                if(xl.Workbook != null){xl.Workbook.Close(true, null, null);}
                if(xl.App != null) {xl.App.Quit();}
            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "Exception");
            }
            finally
            {
                if(xl.Workbook != null){xl.Workbook.Close(true, null, null);}
                if(xl.App != null) {xl.App.Quit();}
            }
        }
    }

    private static void bwg_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: implement some sort of progress reporting
    }

    private static void bwg_RunworkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Statuslabel.label.Text = "Backgroundworker finished";
        (sender as BackgroundWorker).Dispose();
    }

    private static void findMeasureData(Excelattributes xl)
    {
        // Erste 15 Zeilen durchgehen, um herauszufinden wo die Messwerte beginnen (9 + 6 Sicherheit)
        // Nur bis inkl. Spalte AZ
        try
        {
            for(int zeile = 1; zeile <= 15; zeile ++)
            {
                for(int spalte = 1; spalte <= 52; spalte ++)
                {
                    // WICHTIG: (xl.Range...).Text verwenden, um Nullreferenceexception zu vermeiden [?]
                    Object zelleninhalt = (xl.Range.Cells[zeile, spalte] as ExcelRefer.Range).Text;

                    if(zelleninhalt.Equals("DATA START"))
                    {
                        dataPositions.Add(new int[2] {zeile +1, spalte +1});
                        measureDataFound = true;
                    }
                    else if(zelleninhalt.Equals("Number of Samples"))
                    {
                        numberOfSamples = Convert.ToInt32((xl.Range.Cells[zeile, spalte+1] as
                                                           ExcelRefer.Range).Text);
                    }
                }
            }

            if(measureDataFound == true)
            {
                int[,] temp = new int[dataPositions.Count, 2];
                for(int i = 0; i < dataPositions.Count; i ++)
                {
                    temp[i, 0] = dataPositions.ElementAt(i).ToArray()[0];
                    temp[i, 1] = dataPositions.ElementAt(i).ToArray()[1];
                }
                readMeasureData(temp, xl);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "Exception");
        }
    }

    private static void readMeasureData(int[,] temp, Excelattributes xl)
    {
        int[,] zellen = temp;
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        for(int i = zellen[0,0]; i < (zellen[0,0] + numberOfSamples); i ++)
        {
            try
            {
                double weg = Convert.ToDouble((xl.Range.Cells[i, zellen[0,1]] as ExcelRefer.Range).Value2);
                double kraft = Convert.ToDouble((xl.Range.Cells[i, zellen[1,1]] as ExcelRefer.Range).Value2);

                measureData.Add(new PointPair(weg, kraft));

            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "Exception");
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000 + " Sekunden");

        dataComparison[0] = measureData;
        if(smoothing == true)
        {
            smoothMeasureData(xl);
        }
    }

    private static void smoothMeasureData(Excelattributes xl)
    {
        if(temp != null)
        {
            try
            {
                int[] smoothParameters = new int[]{Convert.ToInt32(temp[0]), Convert.ToInt32(temp[1])};
                if(smoothParameters[1] == 0) {smoothParameters[1] = 1;}

                PointPairList smoothedData = new PointPairList();

                MessageBox.Show("Glätte...\n" + smoothParameters[0] + " " + measureData.Count);

                for(int i = (smoothParameters[0] -1); i < measureData.Count; i += smoothParameters[1])
                {
                    double durchschnittX = 0;
                    double durchschnittY = 0;

                    for(int x = i; x > (i - (smoothParameters[0])); x --)
                    {
                        durchschnittX += measureData.ElementAt(x).X;
                        durchschnittY += measureData.ElementAt(x).Y;
                    }

                    durchschnittX /= (double) smoothParameters[0];
                    durchschnittY /= (double) smoothParameters[0];

                    smoothedData.Add(new PointPair(durchschnittX, durchschnittY));
                }

                dataComparison[0] = measureData;
                dataComparison[1] = smoothedData;

                writeToXLSX(smoothedData, xl);
            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "Exception");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void writeToXLSX(PointPairList smoothedData, Excelattributes xl)
    {
        try
        {
            xl.Worksheet = (ExcelRefer.Worksheet) xl.Workbook.Worksheets.get_Item("Sheet1");
            xl.Worksheet.Name = "Smoothed result";
            xl.Workbook.Save();
            xl.Workbook.Close(true, null, null);
            xl.Range = xl.Worksheet.UsedRange;

            Debug.WriteLine("Saved");
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried closing Excel when you've finished?

I can't quite work out where you are gettng `xl` from but the following code works for me:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Workbook book = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\test.xlsx");
Worksheet xl = book.Worksheets.get_Item("sheet1");
xl.Name = "Smoothed result";
book.Save();
book.Close();
```

**Edit**

After seeing the code you are using to open the workbook I think the issue is there. You are opening the file using:

```
xl.Workbook = xl.App.Workbooks.Open(s, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, 
               Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
```

The third parameter is a `ReadOnly` parameter which you have set to `true`. Try setting that to `false`.

Comment: Please look at the EDIT of my question

Comment: @marfuc - I think it might be worth showing the code of that class as the code in my answer renames the sheet successfully. Also, what is `ExcelRefer.Worksheet`?

Comment: @petelids probably something like `using ExcelRefer = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel`.

Comment: @petelids I edited my question and provided the full class. Please ignore everything that you (propably) don't understand because it's not English. Those parts are German then and just for documentation. What ExcelRefer is is also explained in the code

Comment: @Abbas yeah, that's what I was hoping!

Comment: @petelids As it's written here, the code produces HRESULT 0x800401A8, maybe because I'm closing my excel variables in a wrong way

Comment: You are passing true to the Readonly parameter; that should be false. I'm just updating my answer...

Comment: @petelids Thank you very much, I would never have found that error!

Comment: @petelids I had just copied it from another class where I was just importing an excel file and didn't need to change anything